# Can AspectJ replace field invocation to getter/setters?

Tags: java, aspectj, javassist

For example, I have a class with a public field and corresponding getter/setters:

```
public class User {
    public String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name;}
}
```

Now invoke the field `name`:

```
User user = new User();
user.name = "test";
System.out.println(user.name);
```

Is it able to use aspectj to enhance the class to let the bytecode be:

```
User user = new User();
user.setName("test");
System.out.println(user.getName());
```

I know [javassist](http://www.javassist.org) can do this, but can AspectJ do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [pointcut docs](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html) and the`get(FieldPattern)` and `set(FieldPattern)` pointcuts.

There is some [additional writeup in the same doc](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html#d0e5248).

Answer (score 2):

```
User user = new User();
user.setName("Bob");  //<- This line matched the pointcut below
user.name = "Alex";  //<- This line too matched the pointcut below
System.out.println("User name is " + user.name);
```

For the above code in the main method of User class, I wrote the below Aspect

```
public aspect UserAspect {
public pointcut propSet() : set(* User.*);

   void around() : propSet(){
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint.getSignature() + " is being set");
    proceed();
   }
}
```

And the output was..

```
String test.User.name is being set
String test.User.name is being set
User name is Bob
```

So, my understanding is that AspectJ treats member variable assignment and a setter the same way. So, it might not be possible what you were able to do with Javassist

Comment: I didn't try, but maybe the first one is the inside of the setter that is matched and not the setter itself. I'd have to write the test code